# Laravel 4 - Eloquent adding a sub query to array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 to write a reviews system.  Each Product has many reviews an each review has many votes.  I would like to display a "4 out of 5 found this useful" to each review using the votes.

Votes is a separate table linked to Reviews by the Eloquent hasMany() method.

Is there a clever Laravel way of doing this, or am I reduced to using some horrid loops in the controller to add the value to the array?

Below is how I am currently getting the votes with the reviews.

```
$this->reviews = $this->product
  ->reviews()
  ->active()
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  ->with('votes')
  ->get();
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. «Is there a clever Laravel way of doing this» - doing what? Figuring out how to differentiate between useful and non-useful votes? What's a vote? What fields does it have? Lots of information missing.

Comment: I think you're just looking for a simple join. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

Comment: Thanks Jared, I was hoping there might be something build in Eloquent. But a join could work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Borfast, a vote has a simple boolean flag so useful votes are true, non are false. The code above returns an array of reviews containing an array of votes. I'm passing this to the view so I can do a count to get me a total amount of votes, but I would also like to get how many are flagged as true (useful). Ideally this value would be passed in the object created by Eloquent.